# Jack barrel contact diagram?

Tags: power, audio, switches

I've come across this diagram, I researched a bit, but I don't get what this contact is supposed to do. The circuit below is an audio effect, and I'm confused because it apparently doesn't mean that it will power the circuit when the Jack is connected?
What are your thoughts? Help is really appreciated :).

I post the complete diagram, because i have another contact at the output.

[image: barrel contact]
[image: Complete diagram]

Comment: What sort of device is supposed to be connected on the left?

Comment: `I'm confused because it apparently doesn't mean that it will power the circuit when the Jack is connected` I think it does. It adds a DC offset to the AC audio signal. Maybe... This is a tough one.

Comment: a mono audio plug is connected on the left, as well as right, because it's an audio effect, i thought this could be an stereo jack... the name of the circuit is "VOX TONE BENDER", if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jack is being used as a power supply switch. If the symbol used is the normal one for a stereo jack, the plug must have its tip and sleeve shorted together to make battery negative connect to ground when it is plugged in. The signal would be fed into the circuit via the ring contact.

However I suspect that the circuit is drawn slightly wrong, and the battery should be connected to the ring contact. That way a mono plug could be used, as its sleeve should be long enough to touch the ring contact.

Comment: That's correct, the schematic is wrong - see here: http://fuzzcentral.ssguitar.com/voxbender/voxtonebenderschematic.gif. Note that the connections on the in-jack are swapped around. This way, inserting the jack connecte the battery + terminal to the circuit ground (the circuit is negative powered).

Comment: i have other circuits from the same power supply, and they're positive powered, it doesn't affect this circuit behavior?

Comment: @pohm Yes, it would. If another circuit is 'positively powered' (so - terminal connected to ground) you'll short-circuit your power supply if you connect them in series using the guitar cable. As such, the device should be battery powered.

Comment: @pohm if you're building one yourself, there is a version with NPN transistors and a positive supply. For both, see this link for exemple: http://revolutiondeux.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/vox-tonebender-dam-1966.html

Comment: if i battery power this device, but i use the guitar cable to pass through the positive powered devices and finally get to this audio effect, then i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: i think i got the idea, i was scratching my head because the positive side was going to touch the negative side of the power supply but i see now, the positive side is going to be the ground in this case, so nothing is wrong no? :) still, ground on the guitar cables are still connected to different grounds (so positive in 1 case, negative in 2 case), there should be no issue there, am i wrong?, actually figured this out. thanks for your help!

Comment: @Pohm The manipulated signals are capacitively coupled (isolated) so the ground reference and working polarity do not matter outside the box.  The only thing that will be seen by an external device is +9V on the ring contact of a stereo plug on the input with effectively over 5kOhm current limiting resistors so a fairly benign system.  As mentioned the 9V should be on the ring contact to allow a normal mono plug to operate it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on "most logical functionality it **PROBABLY** means:

- Plugging in the input plug enables internal power and connects audio input to the circuitry.
- Pulling out the input plug disables internal power (ie power on/off is achieved via the input plug.
- Also: S1 = DPDT (double pole double throw) passes signal through (or around) the unit without being stomped on by the electronic violence therein.

Note that this is the opposite to what is commonly done. Quite often a socket is provided with a third contact which connects with one of the other two when the plug is OUT and disconnects when the plug is in. This is used to

- CONNECT an internal battery when the plug is OUT,  and
- DISCONNECT the battery when the plug is IN
  so that an external power source can be supplied via the same plug as causes the switching.

Many portable devices which can be operated by internal batteries or internal power supplies work this way. The object is to prevent internal batteries being charged by the external supply, as batteries used in this arrangement are usually non-rechargeable.

**Operation:**

Name the contacts a b c left to right.

- a is ground for signal source & this circuit.
- b is signal for signal-source and this circuit.
- c is connected to a when the plug is in (turning on the power supply) and c is isolated when the plug is out. The 'c to a' connection could also be carried out by a physically independent switch such as a micro-switch operated by the  tip of the plug.

Comment: i've found this schematic which is very similar: http://www.geofex.com/FX_images/tbndrsch.gif